# pthread_self() doesn't return a meaningful thread id?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, self

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
int main(){
    int systid=syscall(186);
    int pt_tid=pthread_self();
    pid_t id=getpid();
    printf("pid=%d,tid=%d,pt_tid=%d\n",id,systid,pt_tid);
    return 0;
}
```

I was running this program on RHEL 5 with gcc4.1.2.

```
$gcc testtid.c -lpthread && ./a.out
pid=35086,tid=35086,pt_tid=1295541984
```

Seems the syscall can give the correct thread id(same like process id), but pthread_self doesn't give meaningful result.

Is it because pthread_self is not portable?

Comment: The value identifies the thread uniquely. It is not intended to be meaningful in any other way. In particular it doesn't have to be equal to any kernel-mamaged identifier.

Comment: So you mean it doesn't indicate any "linux" context value, only for POSIX portability, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read [`man pthread_self`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html), which you should:

> Thread identifiers should be considered opaque: any attempt to use a thread ID other than in pthreads calls is non-portable and can lead to unspecified results.
>
> Thread IDs are guaranteed to be unique only within a process. A thread ID may be reused after a terminated thread has been joined, or a detached thread has terminated.
>
> **The thread ID returned by `pthread_self()` is not the same thing as the kernel thread ID returned by a call to `gettid(2)`**.